# Building a funnel retroactively in Google Analytics

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics

I have a issue with trying to devise a funnel in Google Analytics.

I am not looking to create a goal funnel, as I am looking to do it retroactively on my data so I need to either do the crunching manually or devise a strategy for it.

I wish to see sessions who have navigated from these pages, for example:

```
/ -> Category page A -> Cart -> Conversion
/ -> Category page B -> Cart -> Conversion
/ -> Category page C -> Cart -> Conversion
```

How would I go about creating a funnel like this in Google Analytics and extract this data **retroactively** (emphasis so I do not get recommendations for setting up goal funnels since I want to do this on already processed data)?

I imagine I could use the segmentation sequence, but how reliable is that? I am getting sampled data very quickly and I want to be able to do this for a couple of months back, but I get sampled even after choosing a week. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am hoping that you have a confirmation page for your purchases because that will make this easy. Go into your segensts, and create a new one.

You can create one segment for each funnel. You are going to want to click "sequences" under Advanced.

Filter include Users Sequence start Any user interaction

Step 1: page contains "Category page A "
is followed by
Step 2: page contains "Cart"
is followed by
Step 3: pages contains "Confirmation page"